# 'JSON.parse' replaces ':' with '=>'

Tags: json, ruby

I have a string:

```
{"name":"hector","time":"1522379137221"}
```

I want to parse the string into JSON and expect to get:

```
{"name":"hector","time":"1522379137221"}
```

I am doing:

```
require 'json'
JSON.parse
```

which produces this:

```
{"name"=>"hector","time"=>"1522379137221"}
```

Can someone tell me how I can keep `:`? I don't understand why it adds `=>`.

Comment: It turns your string into a hash. That’s probably what you want. (You don’t parse a string “into JSON” – JSON is a string format. You parse a JSON string into something you can work with.)

Comment: i need to push json parsed output to external api endpoint that accept `:` not `=>`. can you please tell me where can i read difference between `:` and `=>` as well

Comment: If you need to send JSON to an external API, why would you convert it to non-JSON? Just pass the JSON string through directly.

Comment: `{ "a": 1 }` is the same as `{ :"a" => 1 }`, which the same as`{ :a => 1 }`. Regardless of how you define it Ruby will return it in the second or third form.

Comment: Are you sure you want to parse your string **into** JSON? Your example suggests you want to convert it into a hash by parsing it **as** JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you parse the json data you should see it in the programming language that you are using.

Ruby uses `=>` to separated the key from the value in hash (while json uses `:`).

So the ruby output is correct and the data is ready for you to manipute in your code. When you convert your hash to json, the json library will convert the `=>` back to `:`.

Answer (score -1):

JSON does not have symbol class. Hence, nothing in JSON data corresponds to Ruby symbol. Under a trivial conversion from JSON to Ruby like `JSON.parse`, you cannot have a symbol in the output.